# Monitors setup in local

Tags: cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

I am trying to setup monitoring in local as mentioned in https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/operation-guide/monitor/#instructions
Having these errors for http://host.docker.internal:9098/metrics, http://cadence:9090/metrics as shown in below image.
Can please let me know how we can resolve this, Thanks

[Endpoints state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oot0.png)

Answer (score 1):

9090 is Prometheus itself. Are you configuring a different port? https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/68fb2e60d1a2bff77c66acf60c954c9d19f9e5f5/docker/docker-compose-es-v7.yml#L14

But anyway, this is not something important so if you like, you can ignore this error.

9098 is the client sdk . The doc is assuming that you are setting it up correctly: https://github.com/uber/cadence-java-samples/blob/cdd43b6a65bf537ef6c77262a56cd22308d75e06/src/main/java/com/uber/cadence/samples/hello/HelloMetric.java#L53

https://github.com/uber-common/cadence-samples/blob/beacf223ab727c7fd114236f40806497c6d0aabd/config/development.yaml#L7